Issue with Singularity Command Recognition for Fastq.gz Files
I am developing a shotgun metagenomics pipeline using Snakemake and Singularity, but I'm facing difficulties when trying to execute the Singularity command within Snakemake to analyze fastq.gz files. Then I decided to run only the Singularity command to understand the error, and the problem is that the files are not recognized. My Snakefile is in another directory, and when I made a copy of the data to this directory, the pipeline worked. I don't understand why the Singularity command doesn't work in the original directory of the data.
singularity exec -B /mnt/share/Equipamentos_NTO/Med_Pers/Illumina_NextSeq/Corridas/run142/BIOINFO/METAGEN/results/fastqc:/output docker://staphb/fastqc fastqc -o /output /mnt/share/Equipamentos_NTO/Med_Pers/Illumina_NextSeq/Corridas/run142/BIOINFO/METAGEN/Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz /mnt/share/Equipamentos_NTO/Med_Pers/Illumina_NextSeq/Corridas/run142/BIOINFO/METAGEN/Undetermined_S0_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz


Using cached SIF image
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "pt_BR.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Skipping '/mnt/share/Equipamentos_NTO/Med_Pers/Illumina_NextSeq/Corridas/run142/BIOINFO/METAGEN/Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping '/mnt/share/Equipamentos_NTO/Med_Pers/Illumina_NextSeq/Corridas/run142/BIOINFO/METAGEN/Undetermined_S0_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read

permissions:
drwxr-xr-x 2 catg catg    0 abr  1 12:26 results
-r-xr-xr-x 1 catg catg 608M jan 13 16:06 Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
-r-xr-xr-x 1 catg catg 606M jan 13 16:08 Undetermined_S0_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz


Don't you have to mount the folders you want to use via --bind?

As you suggested, I tried to use --bind. It worked using only singularity! But still not working in my snakemake rule.
My singularity command: singularity exec --bind /mnt/share/Equipamentos_NTO/Med_Pers/Illumina_NextSeq/Corridas/run142/BIOINFO/METAGEN:/mnt/mydata docker://staphb/fastqc fastqc -o /mnt/mydata /mnt/mydata/Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz /mnt/mydata/Undetermined_S0_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz

rule fastqc:     input:         "{results_dir}/{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz",         "{results_dir}/{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz"     output:         "{results_dir}/results/fastqc/{sample}_R1_001_fastqc.zip",         "{results_dir}/results/fastqc/{sample}_R2_001_fastqc.zip",         "{results_dir}/results/fastqc/{sample}_R1_001_fastqc.html",         "{results_dir}/results/fastqc/{sample}_R2_001_fastqc.html"     params: results_dir = RESULTS_DIR     shell: "singularity exec --bind {params.results_dir}/results/fastqc:/mnt/mydata docker://staphb/fastqc fastqc -o /mnt/mydata {input}

Please read about SIngularity and Snakemake in the Snakemake docs. You don't need to (and probably should not) directly call a Snakemake rule with Singularity but rather let Snakemake itself do all the binding.

To troubleshoot the problem I would try to:

check the mounting directories to be sure that the directory containing the fastq.gz files is included in the list:
echo $SINGULARITY_BINDPATH

check files paths to be sure that your fastq.gz are here:
ls /mnt/share/Equipamentos_NTO/Med_Pers/Illumina_NextSeq/Corridas/run142/BIOINFO/METAGEN/

read one of your fastq.gz to be sure about accessibility:
cat /mnt/share/Equipamentos_NTO/Med_Pers/Illumina_NextSeq/Corridas/run142/BIOINFO/METAGEN/Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz > /dev/null


